# Why is the table layout property not keeping the cell dimensions fixed

Tags: html, css

Hi Im using html tables + css properties as said in my school textbook(were learning this in class). Basically the error I have is the fact that the layout is not making much of a difference to the dimensions of the table which I have specified in the format.
See the code for more references:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Employees table</title>
    <style>
        body{background-color:RGB(255,251,214)}
        table,td,tr,th{border:1px solid blue}
        tr{hover:background-color:blue}
        th{text-align:center}
        table{table-layout:fixed;}
        td{vertical-align:middle}
        h2{color:red}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Table layout fixed</h2>
<table style="table-layout:auto">
    <tr>
        <th width=" 40%">Emp-id</th>
        <th width = 30%>Name</th>
        <th width = 17%>Basic</th>
        <th width = 28%>HRA</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>101</td><td>Ajay</td><td>20000000000000</td><td>300</td></tr>
    <tr><td>102</td><td>Shashi</td><td>15000000000000000</td><td>2800</td></tr>
    <tr><td>103</td><td>Mukesh</td><td>130000</td><td>2000</td></tr>
</table>
<h2>Table layout auto</h2>
<table style="table-layout:auto">
    <tr>
        <th width= "40%">Emp-id</th>
        <th width = 30%>Name</th>
        <th width = 10%>Basic</th>
        <th width = 28%>HRA</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>101</td><td>Ajay</td><td>20000000000000</td><td>300</td></tr>
    <tr><td>102</td><td>Shashi</td><td>15000000000000000</td><td>2800</td></tr>
    <tr><td>103</td><td>Mukesh</td><td>130000</td><td>2000</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And also ps can someone give me a more clear definition of what are table layouts

Comment: Do you want all your columns of the same width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in your code.

1. Your total percent is more than 100%, which will render the table wrong than you intended.
2. More importantly, you had override `table-layout` in both tables to `auto`, so `table-layout: fixed` won't work, thus you can't see the different.

Now with that corrected, you will see the string data you wrote in the `td` of fixed table get overflow to outside, and with layout auto, the cell will just expand till it force all other cell to minimum width, and then make the table larger to fit the content. To fix this, you can use `word-break: break-all` in `td` to force break the string to fit the cell's defined width.

Oh and you wrote `:hover` wrong too so it won't work, fixed it in the demo for you.

```css
body{background-color:RGB(255,251,214)}
table,td,tr,th{border:1px solid blue}
tr:hover{background-color:blue}
th{text-align:center}
table{table-layout:fixed;width: 100%;}
td{vertical-align:middle; word-break: break-all}
h2{color:red}
```

```html
<table style="">
    <tr>
        <th width="35%">Emp-id</th>
        <th width="30%">Name</th>
        <th width="17%">Basic</th>
        <th width="18%">HRA</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>101</td><td>Ajay</td><td>20000000000000</td><td>300</td></tr>
    <tr><td>102</td><td>Shashi</td><td>150000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</td><td>2800</td></tr>
    <tr><td>103</td><td>Mukesh</td><td>130000</td><td>2000</td></tr>
</table>
<h2>Table layout auto</h2>
<table style="table-layout:auto">
    <tr>
        <th width= "30%">Emp-id</th>
        <th width ="40%">Name</th>
        <th width ="10%">Basic</th>
        <th width ="20%">HRA</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>101</td><td>Ajay</td><td>20000000000000</td><td>300</td></tr>
    <tr><td>102</td><td>Shashi</td><td>150000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</td><td>2800</td></tr>
    <tr><td>103</td><td>Mukesh</td><td>130000</td><td>2000</td></tr>
</table>
```